# Teamsite Cleanup

Tags: content-management-system, teamsite, autonomy

I was wondering what is the best way to do a clean up of autonomy teamsite7.  I basically have loads of dcr files that are not in use anymore and want to delete these.  Whats the best way to search through the CMS and identify what .page and dcrs are published on the live site and what is not used and can be deleted so I dont have to go through manually?

Comment: I go into file system instead of teamsite and use Beyond Compare Sync. They are very helpful. To identify old files you can use teamsite search with modified/created date.

Answer (score 1):

Template-based pages use extended attributes to associate a generated page with a DCR and Presentation template.

In the past, I have written Perl scripts that would generate a list of the active DCRs. You can then compare the DCRs in the workarea to that list and delete those that aren't on the list.

Basically set it up as a cron job that cleaned up the "templatedata" directory once a month.

Answer (score 0):

If I had this particular scenario, I think my first thought would be to run a simulated comparison deployment with OpenDeploy to generate the list of files that were in the workarea but not on the webserver. You could parse the resulting log with a perl script (or whatever your favorite language is) to then remove those files.